# Missing installed package on Docker image using docker run command

Tags: docker

I have run some docker images using this command

```
C:\Users\muhammad.iqbal>docker run -it fedora
[root@13d5c5b5683b /]# yum install -y nano
```

This images works and i could install `nano` package inside this fedora images.
But when exit the images and tried to run again the installed packages, nano, it's said,

```
C:\Users\muhammad.iqbal>docker run -it fedora
[root@8f49adc7b3af /]# nano
bash: nano: command not found
```

It's said nano is not installed. Why is this happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because your image is new each time.**

`docker run` will create a container.

**Short answer:** (use `docker exec`)

```
docker run -it --name=my-image fedora
#yum install -y nano

docker exec -ti my-image nano
```

**Long answer**:

You can display the running container by using `docker ps` command.
Or displaying the running and stopped container by using `docker ps -a`

When you want to work on an image, you will need to create a container in order to keep the data and play with it.

`docker run` will create the container.

By specifying `--name=my-image` it will set your container name to: `my-image`, which will be used to identify your container.

You can stop your image by using the command: `docker stop my-image`
And you can start it by using the command: `docker start my-image`

Your container will automatically stop if there is no background process running. But you can go inside by using the command: `docker exec -ti my-image sh`. And then execute the command you want. You can use sh, bash, or any command that your image is using.

Keep in mind that docker run will create a new container, meaning that you'll start from the default image. Here is the power of docker.

Comment: Is there a way so the docker images recognize the installed packages ? so each time i `docker run` that images, the package will be still there

Comment: Unfortunately no : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
You have to use `docker exec`, otherwise you can create a docker image who contains the package